# How to title a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code that prints out descriptive statistics with `df.describe` for each class of a categorical variable

```
for i in list(merged.Response.unique()):
  print(merged[(merged.Response==i)].describe().round(2))
```

and it returns

```
       OrderCount  OrderAvgSize  AvgDeliverCost  AvgOrderValue  CustomerValue
count      687.00        687.00          687.00         687.00         687.00
mean        24.75         13.45            4.56           9.61         243.91
std          7.04          3.35            0.17           1.95         107.45
min         11.00          7.00            4.13           5.85          83.27
25%         20.00         11.00            4.45           8.18         167.44
50%         24.00         13.00            4.57           9.34         213.08
75%         29.00         15.00            4.67          10.51         289.74
max         51.00         24.00            4.97          15.75         700.80
       OrderCount  OrderAvgSize  AvgDeliverCost  AvgOrderValue  CustomerValue
count      1099.0       1099.00         1099.00        1099.00        1099.00
mean         17.2          6.85            4.08           5.18          97.88
std          12.8          2.47            0.24           1.45         101.26
min           1.0          2.00            3.24           2.40           5.72
25%           7.0          5.00            3.89           4.12          31.38
50%          14.0          7.00            4.13           5.21          62.58
75%          24.0          8.00            4.22           5.86         130.90
max          55.0         21.00            4.91          13.46         686.46
       OrderCount  OrderAvgSize  AvgDeliverCost  AvgOrderValue  CustomerValue
count      392.00        392.00          392.00         392.00         392.00
mean        12.41         11.46            4.44          10.13         125.04
std          3.75          3.34            0.19           1.94          43.91
min          3.00          6.00            4.02           6.98          36.92
25%         10.00          9.00            4.31           8.71          92.68
50%         13.00         10.00            4.38           9.30         121.58
75%         15.00         13.00            4.51          11.00         148.64
max         26.00         22.00            4.94          16.25         266.56
```

Is there any way I can title each summary table so I know which class is which?

I treid the following with the pandas styler, but despite titling the dataframe, it only printed one of them and it doesn't look as good (I'm in google colab btw):

```
for i in list(merged.Response.unique()):
  test = merged[(merged.Response==i)].describe().round(2).style.set_caption(i)

test
```

```
                               AmznPrime
OrderCount  OrderAvgSize    AvgDeliverCost  AvgOrderValue   CustomerValue
count   392.000000  392.000000  392.000000  392.000000  392.000000
mean    12.410000   11.460000   4.440000    10.130000   125.040000
std 3.750000    3.340000    0.190000    1.940000    43.910000
min 3.000000    6.000000    4.020000    6.980000    36.920000
25% 10.000000   9.000000    4.310000    8.710000    92.680000
50% 13.000000   10.000000   4.380000    9.300000    121.580000
75% 15.000000   13.000000   4.510000    11.000000   148.640000
max 26.000000   22.000000   4.940000    16.250000   266.560000
```

All help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you post some sample data?

Comment: It only prints once because you are setting it to test each time in the loop. So will only print whatever test was set to last

Comment: just add a `print(i)` before each line printing the describe?

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
merged.groupby("Response").describe().round(2)
```

To match your expected output, do `stack/unstack`:

```
merged.groupby("Response").describe().stack(level=1).unstack(level=0)
```